# Using JAX-WS RI from JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, jax-ws

I am deploying a JAX-WS client as part of a Java EE application on JBoss (5.0.1 if it matters). Since JBoss is making its own JAX-WS implementation (JBoss-WS) visible to the deployed applications, JBoss-WS is used instead of the JAX-WS RI (reference implementation) which is already included in the VM's standard API.

Because of bugs and limitations in JBoss-WS, I would rather like to use the VM's RI, but there seem to be no way to enforce this. Does someone know a possibility for using the VM's JAX-WS implementation from code, which is deployed on JBoss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's a very old question, but I had the same sort of problem recently.
I believe you can delete all of the jaxws jars from `$JBOSS_HOME/lib/endorsed` and put there the newest jars taken from **JAXWS-RI** (e.g. from this [archive](http://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.6/JAXWS2.2.6-20120220.zip)). Even if this is not a direct answer to your question, it should be a decent work around.

Comment: At least worth an upvote for a decent suggestion :) I haven't tried it, since I am not working on that project anymore, but I assume that your suggestion won't work, since JBoss needs its own JAX-WS implementation to e.g. offer SOAP services.

Comment: Well, in my case it worked, I must say I didn't try invoking a web service running on JBoss. I hope it does. I'll report back ;)

Comment: I tried invoking a web service running on JBoss, and it works as expected.